# Guessing date format with PHP

Tags: php, html, date

I have a user input in web-form in HTML5 `type="date"` field. Then this entered value (together with others) is saved as JSON document in MySQL database. Now I need to extract that date and print it into generated MS Word document with one given format. Great! But as you know HTML5 date field accepts date format depending on user locales, settings, etc. I noticed that all dates entered in different browsers are saved in DB in "Y-m-d" format. Is this really so in all the cases? Can I rely on this format for future usage? Could not find any specification information on the topic.
If one can **not** rely on "Y-m-d" format are there any PHP libraries for "guessing" date format?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you saving JSON document in MySQL database instead of some more suitable document database (e.g. MongoDB)?

Anyway, based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) and [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome) the displayed date format differs from the actual value. The date value in the HTTP Request will be always formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd`, which is the [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) format and I guess it should be reliable.

In PHP you can process date strings with the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. This class supports many different date formats. For example:

```
// timezone is set based on your system preferences if not set
$date1 = new DateTime('2017-04-27', new DateTimeZone('+00:00'));
$date2 = new DateTime('27 April 2017', new DateTimeZone('+00:00'));
$date3 = new DateTime('2017-04-27T00:00:00+00:00');

var_dump($date1 == $date2); // bool(true)
var_dump($date1 == $date3); // bool(true)
```

If the date string is wrong, an exception is thrown:

```
try {
    $date = new DateTime('2017 4 27');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2017 4 27) at position 5 (4): Unexpected character
}
```

So, in your case you can you this class for date validation and than proper output formatting, e.g.:

```
$dateString = '2017-04-27T14:22:11+00:00';
try {
    $date = new DateTime($dateString);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-04-27
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Lukas, for pointing to MDN and Google Developers. Looks like I googled too little to find answer by myself. The most important part is that request is always sent in yyyy-mm-dd form.

Comment: My whole application is MySQL-dependent. But I need to build dynamic forms for entering hard-copy document attributes. New JSON type fields started in MySQL 5.7.6 really help me a lot in extending app functionality.

Comment: When someone asks a question, he expects to receive an actual answer to his question. People doesn't need to be judged about their development choices. If you have a problem with other's people choices, then the problem is only yours. Please, this forum is meant to be a place to have solutions to asked questions and not to make everyone think the same and do the same. There are many reasons why anyone could choose a database over another.